# Issue while fetching device id using cordova pludin in ionic framework

Tags: android, ios, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

Can anyone please help me out to get deviceid for ios, windows and android devices using cordova plugins in ionic framework for a hybrid application. As i am new to this hybrid application development struggling with this from more than one work. Any help can be appreciable. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/),

Usage:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDevice) {

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();
var cordova = $cordovaDevice.getCordova();
var model = $cordovaDevice.getModel();
var platform = $cordovaDevice.getPlatform();
var uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
var version = $cordovaDevice.getVersion();

}, false);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use IDFVPlugin :**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin.git
```

In your controller :

```
 window.IDFVPlugin.getIdentifier(function(result){ 
    alert(result); 
 },function(error){ 
    alert(error); 
 });
```

Sources :

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-iphone-unique-id-udid-in-ionic-framework-script/9575